# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.appcenter.ms api.appcenter.ms:443 throws on uploading files to appcenter

Tags: junit, appium, visual-studio-app-center

I am working on sample tests for mobile application and to upload and run in AppCenter. I have tried with XamarinUITest and C# combination; test files uploaded and ran successfully. On trying test files with Appium, Java and Junit and tried to upload it in AppCenter throws Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.appcenter.ms api.appcenter.ms:443 in Terminal.

The snippet I am using to upload is:
appcenter test run appium --app "Appium/JunitiOS" --devices "Appium/iphone" --app-path pathToFile.ipa --test-series "test" --locale "en_US" --build-dir target/upload

Note: given corresponding file paths in the snippet.

and get the below in Terminal:
Preparing tests... done.
Validating arguments... done.
Creating new test run... done.
Validating application file... done.
Uploading files... failed.
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.appcenter.ms api.appcenter.ms:443

Environment: darwin
    App Upload Id: Appium/JunitiOS
    Timestamp: 1554114371409
    Operation: RunAppiumTestsCommand
    Exit Code: 3

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when there's some sort of network issue (either WiFi dropping out, a corporate firewall or proxy or a DNS issue are likely culprits)

**Things to try if the successful upload is running on a different machine or a different network**

- Check the failing upload over a different network
- [Make sure you can see the URLs and IPs from the machine you're running on](https://intercom.help/appcenter/general-questions/urls-and-ip-addresses-to-whitelist-for-app-center)
- If that fails - reach out to support using the App Center portal and a support engineer will help you get up and running

**Things to try if the successful upload is running on the same machine on the same network**

- Double check that the UITest tests are still working successfully
- Check that you don't have any corporate firewall policies which could be blocking specific files
- If that fails - reach out to support using the App Center portal and a support engineer will help you get up and running

I would also recommend running the command again using `--debug` - you should be able to see the API calls being sent and identify at which point the uploads are failing (and if it's the same point every time).

Comment: Thank You @Owen Niblock. I had got this on different network, whereas uploading files work fine on my company network.

Comment: Cool - if you need to get it working on that other network and have no joy with the above, I would recommend reaching out to us on support. Please do accept my answer if you're all up and running though! It'll make me happy :-)